# Rails returns HTTP 500 for every page with no error log after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Today I tried to install a gem using bundler.  It complained about super-user privileges so I ran it to install to `vendor/bundle`, and then all of a sudden every page in my app returns HTTP 500 for seemingly no reason.  I re-ran bundler to install globally, and that didn't solve the problem.

In typical rails fashion, it just exits with the 500 error page without printing anything to the logs.  Routing is functioning normally, the console says it renders the appropriate view, and active record seems to be working as normal, but after all of that it just shows an error page.  No errors on the console or in `logs/`.

I'm not sure why bundler would cause this issue but I'm completely out of ideas.  I've done a good bit of googling but all of the other similar situations I've found were because of a misconfigured model or database, which I know with certainty isn't the case.  If anyone more familiar with Rails than me could give me a place to start I'd be very grateful.

Update:  Running `bundler doctor` fails b/c the directory `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bundler` doesn't exist - looking for issues related to this.

Comment: Make sure you have set your Rails logger correctly in the config: Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("log/#{Rails.env}.log"). Put that in environment.rb

Comment: also might be worth checking the `logs` folder in the rails directory

Comment: @AbePetrillo what is the `config` symbol there?  Undefined variable for me.  Also, for what it's worth, the console logging seems to be working normally, and everything in the console is going to the `logs/` dir, there's just no error message anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Solved; ultimately this was because I forgot to delete an old requirement in `application.js`.  It still seems absolutely ludicrous to me that rails would exit 500 without an error message with no way to access more verbose debug logs